# What is the Next.js type for the Redirect object?

Tags: typescript, next.js

Next.js can be configured to [redirect](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/redirects) like so:

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/about',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

The redirect objects (below) can be defined dynamically:

```
{
  source: '/about',
  destination: '/',
  permanent: true,
}
```

for example:

```
const myRedirect: WhatTypeGoesHere = {source: '/about', dest...}
```

What is the TypeScript type of the object above? If it exists, how did you find it? I looked everywhere short of scouring the entire [Next.js repo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js). If the answer is *"There is no type for this"*, then is it pretty common for Next.js built-ins not to have types?

I know how to define my own interface/type for this, only interested in what's available "out of the box".

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/fabab8cf05da106410d97d818adf2f6b4742d614/packages/next/src/server/config-shared.ts#L387-L399? That leads you on to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/fabab8cf05da106410d97d818adf2f6b4742d614/packages/next/src/lib/load-custom-routes.ts#L49-L71. If you use e.g. `/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */` in your config file you should just be able to "click through" to it in your IDE.

Comment: So it looks like: `import { Redirect } from 'next/dist/lib/load-custom-routes';` in the project. Is it a bad practice to go to dist?

Comment: In that file it says _"internal type used for validation (not user facing)"_, but given `import { Redirect } from "next";` gives you a _different_ type it's hard to see what else you could do if you want to use it. I'd consider configuration part of the public API for a tool like Next.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract it from the `NextConfig` type

```
import {NextConfig} from "next"

type RedirectFunction = NextConfig["redirects"]
//   ^? Promise<Redirect[]>
type RedirectArray = Awaited<RedirectFunction>
//   ^? Redirect[]
type Redirect = RedirectArray[number]
//   ^? Redirect
```

Comment: This is the wrong type. See comments on the question.

Comment: How is it wrong? "internal type used for validation (not user-facing)" doesn't mean wrong. It just means internal usage. 

You're looking for a type that can be passed to the config. My answer extract the type from the config type.

Comment: The correct import is `import { Redirect } from 'next/dist/lib/load-custom-routes'`, not `import {NextConfig} from "next"`. They are different types.